# jQuery common factor of functions with events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this code:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    var gold;
    var silver;
    var copper;

    $("#gold").change(function(){
        gold = $(this).val();
    });
    $("#silver").change(function(){
        silver = $(this).val();
    });
    $("#copper").change(function(){
        copper = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

It just updates the variable whenever the textfield changes, this is the html:

```
<input type="text" id="gold">
<input type="text" id="silver">
<input type="text" id="copper">
```

If i had to declare something like:

```
$("#copper").change(function(){
    copper = $(this).val();
});
```

for every variable ive got, what can i do when i have over 100 variables? I want to avoid getting elements 1 by 1 with theyr events...

I have tried something like this:

```
var gold = dynamicValue("gold");

function dynamicValue(element){
    $("#" + element).change(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    });
}
```

But doesn't seem to work...

Comment: _$("input[type='text']").change(function(){_ ... should do all it for you. You can use a class to each element too, something like: _$(".myClass").change(function(){_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're structure is always like that I would recommend something like this.

```
var values = {};

$('input').change(function(){
   values[this.id] = this.value;
});
```

Like this it will create an object with the IDs as keys and in input values as the key value.

```
values = {
   gold: 'something',
   copper: 'something',
   silver: 'comething'
}
```

and you will be able to get them anytime

```
var gold = values.gold;
```

If you get `undefined` it will mean that the input has not yet been changed. Example below

```js
var values = {};

$('input').change(function() {
  values[this.id] = this.value;
  $('div').text(JSON.stringify(values)); // this line is only for the example
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="gold">
<input type="text" id="silver">
<input type="text" id="copper">
<input type="text" id="gold1">
<input type="text" id="silver2">
<input type="text" id="copper4">

<div></div>
```

Comment: im a sad bear, whenever i use var gold = values.gold; or whaver value from the array it doesnt work, getting undefined... But the lazy alert(values.gold) works fine wtf?

Comment: Hmm, might have not been specific enough. You have to be in the same scope where the value was defined. If you define the value in document.ready you can only use it there.

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="metal-input" id="gold">
<input type="text" class="metal-input" id="silver">
<input type="text" class="metal-input" id="copper">
```

**jQuery**

```
var metals = {};

$('.metal-input').on('input', function() {

    metals[this.id] = $(this).val();
    console.log(metals);
});
```

Comment: What about if user pastes some value using only the context menu? `input` event would be better in this case: `$('.metal-input').on('input', function(){...});`

Answer (score 1):

Use a class and use the id as a key

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
  var metals = 
      { gold : null, silver : null, copper : null}

  $(".inputs").change(function(){
    metals[this.id] = $(this).val();
    console.log(metals);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="gold">gold</label><input type="text" id="gold" class="inputs">
<label for="silver">silver</label><input type="text" id="silver" class="inputs">
<label for="copper">copper</label><input type="text" id="copper" class="inputs">
```